# Sub-filtering html using xpath

Tags: symfony, xpath, web-crawler

I am doubting about the best way to achieve that. I am using Symfony Crawler, and I have this filter:

```
$myData = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="container"]');
```

Then I loop over them like that:

```
      foreach ($myData as $domElementData) {
```

But with divFirst I get a block with links, divs, ... which I need to filter and put in an array for each block. My first approach was to loop over each block (divFirst) and then subfilter, but I'm not sure if I should create a second subcrawler for that?

The other option would be doing something like:

```
$subData1 = $crawler->filterXPath('//*[contains(@id, "date")]');
$subData2 = $crawler->filterXPath('//*[contains(@id, "price")]');
...
```

Then loop the first and use its index to include in the first array all the information of fest of fields?

```
foreach (subData1 as $index=>$subData) {
  $theFinalData [$index]['subdata1'] = subData1;
  $theFinalData [$index]['subdata2'] = subData2;
  ...
```

But this last choice seems weird and even ugly. Any opinions?

The html I am trying to read looks like that:

```
<div class="container1234Y53">
  <div id="date12345">12/02/2014</div>
  <div id="price">80£</div>
  <div id="numberofpeople">4</div>
</div>
  <div class="container1234X123">
  <div id="date3451">2/06/2014</div>
  <div id="price">30£</div>
  <div id="numberofpeople">1</div>
</div>
....
```

The result should be an array like that:

```
container[0]['date'] = 12/02/2014
container[0]['price'] = 80
container[0]['numberofpeople'] = 4
container[1]['date'] = 2/06/2014
container[1]['price'] = 30
container[1]['numberofpeople'] = 1
....
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: probably the question is more like, how do I fetch each element in the nodes using Symfony Crawler?

Comment: There may be other (simpler) alternatives. Show your XML file and explain exactly what you want to extract.

Comment: yep, you are absolutely right. It's not xml but html, just updated the original post with a sample. Thanks again :-).

Comment: Where is `divFirst` in your source example? Is it wrapping those nodes? And what to your want to extract? The whole `container` node? A collection of `date` or `price` strings?

Comment: Ideally, an array of n elements containing each elemnt in the array the date, number,  etc...

Comment: I have added some more info. Note that the examples are just that, examples, as what I am trying to do is understand how Crawl works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I answer myself hoping it helps someone else.

You have to create a new Crawler, like it is detailed here: http://www.ymc.ch/en/webscraping-in-php-with-guzzle-http-and-symfony-domcrawler

Basically, the first one will search for the first group:

```
// crate crawler instance from body HTML code
$crawler = new Crawler($response->getBody(true));

// apply css selector filter
$myData = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="container"]');
$result = array();
```

Then you can iterate over the results, creating a new Crawler and extracting results for this new searches with this new crawler:

```
// iterate over filter results
foreach ($myData as $i => $content) {

    // create crawler instance for result
    $cralwer = new Crawler($content);
    // extract the values needed
    $result[$i] = array(
        'topic' => $crawler->filterXPath('//*[contains(@id, "date")]')->text();
...
```

I was not sure (I still am) if this is the best solutions in terms of performance, as the crawler is created several times, but seems better than the first solution in terms of coding styling.